# Random Walk on n+1 cycle, T is time such that walk returns to the initial vertex.

Tags: probability, random-walk

Random Walk on n+1 cycle, T is time such that walk returns to the initial vertex.  Find the probability of visiting every vertex prior to time T.

Where walk moves clockwise w.p. $p \in (0,1)$ and counter-clockwise w.p. $(1-p)$.

This seems to be similar to gamblers ruin or any random walk with boundaries.

My approach is to consider : $S_0 = k$ where $k = 0,1,\ldots,n$

It would move to $k-1$ with probability $1-p$ so then consider the probability of hitting $k+1$ before hitting $k$

and similarly, walk moves to $k+1$ with probability $p$ then consider probability of hitting $k-1$ before $k$.

Im not sure if this is the correct approach, it seems along the correct lines but not quite.

Comment: It might help to consider separately the cases when $n+1$ is even and odd. For example, when $n=2$, then $\mathbb P(T=3)>0$ but when $n=3$, $T$ is even with probability $1$.

Comment: @Math1000 if $n=2$ and it isn't a lazy random walk, i.e. can stay in place, then how would $P(T = 3) > 0$, if not lazy then it has to move that would force $P(T=2) = 1$ cause it would start at $a$ move to $b$ necessarily at time 1 then necessarily move back to $a$ at time 2.

Comment: We are considering the $n+1$ cycle, so there would be $3$ vertices. Going in one direction three times would bring us back to the start.

Comment: @Math1000 you are correct, I for whatever reason reverted to working with n vertices

Comment: Slightly irrelevant, but why did you choose to have $n+1$ vertices instead of $n$ vertices?

Answer (score 1):

I think this reduces to the gamblers ruin problem. Let me know if you think this sketch is reasonable -- I'd be happy to provide more detail.

Let's say we start at node $0$. We either move to $1$ or $n$ in the first step. Let's consider the case we move to $1$, since the other one is similar.

We are now asking about the probability that a biased random walker on $\mathbb{Z}$ that starts at $1$ reaches $n$ before it reaches $0$; the main point is that if we start the walk with $X_0 = 0, X_1 = 1$, then reaching $n$ before hitting $0$ again is equivalent to touching every node before reaching $0$ again.

Here the bias is that the random walker moves up with probability $p$ (a clockwise motion) and down with probability $1-p$ (counter clockwise motion). (For the other case the bias is swapped.)

The biased gamblers ruin is analyzed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin#Unfair_coin_flipping

Comment: Yeah I was thinking something along these terms. What I was thinking is I have to condition on the first move being clockwise or counter-clockwise. Then from there consider hitting time. So if we start at $0$ then more to $1$ then I need to consider the hitting time to reach $n$ before reaching $0$ again, and flipped if we move from $0$ to $n$. But don't see quite how to connect it all to find the probability of the cover time or time to hit all non-starting vertices is less than T. Or in notation $\mathbb{P}($ cover time of remaining n vxs $< T)$

Comment: @oliverjones I think the key simplifying idea is that you don't need to consider the cover time. Conditioning on stepping to 1 first, covering the graph before hitting zero again is equivalent to hitting n-1 before 0 -- this is because any path from 1 to n-1 that doesn't touch 0 must cover all the other nodes. After conditioning based on the first step, its the same as biased gambler ruin.

Comment: I think you mean hitting $n$ before $0$ because it is on $n+1$ vertices but I think I understand. The initial move gives two disjoint scenarios so the probability I am after should be the sum of moving to $1$ and reaching $n$ before ruin i.e. hitting $0$ summed with moving to $n$ and reaching $1$ prior to ruin or $0$, which this second one as you stated before will be similar just the bias will switch. Is that correct? (For some reason I am not able to @ anyone)

Comment: Something along the line $P($ hit all vertices before return to $0) = P($ reach n before $0 \mid X_1 = 1)*P(X_1=1) + P($ reach 1 before $0 \mid X_1 = n ) * P(X_1 = n)$

Comment: @oliverjones Yeah, that's what I had in mind. ( You don't need to @ when replying to answers or questions, the author is automatically alerted. ) You can also check the calculation by simulating it. :-)

Comment: Why the downvote? This seems like a perfectly reasonable answer. http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/FE-Notes/4700-07-Notes-GR.pdf is useful for a closed form of the probability.

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect that there are $n+1$ vertices and $p$ probability of going clockwise.